# GCP PubSub issue while publishing message to Topic from local machine/On-premise machine - Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while callling target function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

**Problem Statement:**

- Want to do pubsub PoC in **python on windows 10 machine**, i.e. how can publisher app pubishes messages on 'topic', and that publisher application will be running on non-gcp environment i.e. in this case local machine.
- I  have followed this document https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publish-receive-messages-client-library or [github-repo](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/HEAD/samples/snippets/publisher.py),
  nothing change in code used from google doccument as it is,

  ```
    from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

    project_id = "pubsub-dev-project"
    topic_id = "topic-test-1"
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(project_id, topic_id)
    for n in range(1, 10):
       data_str = f"Message number {n}"
       data = data_str.encode("utf-8")
       future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
       print(future.result())

    print(f"Published messages to {topic_path}.")`
  ```

but got this error,

`**google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline ogoogle.api_core.exceptions.RetryError:  Deadline of 600.0s exceeded while callling target function, last exception: 503 failed to connect to all addresses**`

I beleive after this line of code `future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)` it is giving above exception.

**Configuraton done:**

1. I have servie account(SA) created in another project e.g. **"test-dev-project"**.
2. Above SA has given required permissions such as roles/pubsub.publisher, roles/pubsub.viewer, roles/pubsub.subscriber on pubsub project e.g. **"pubsub-dev-project"**.
3. Environment variable added in users level environment variable for **"GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"** and set path of JSON file.
4. gcloud configured using gcloud+python package installer downloaded from google document
5. PubSub API is enabled on this google pubsub project **"pubsub-dev-project"**
6. google--cloud-pubsub verion tried/used in this PoC 0.40.0, 2.12.0, 2.12.1

Also went through many google docs, blogs but couldn't find any solution for above error. Followed this [troubleshooting-guide](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/troubleshooting#client-libraries-issue-tracker-python) but many things/question comes in mind,

1. what things/configuration require to run pubsliher app on-local/on-premise machine to publishing message on topic.
2. System hardware(CPU, processor, network badwidth) configuration really matters if yes then what could be lowset configuration require to run pub-sub app
3. Also is google allowing traffic coming from non-google environment in pubsub case.

Comment: As you are getting [`retry-error`](https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/exceptions.html) with  [`503 failed to connect to all addresses`](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/503-service-unavailable),this is might be happening due to the credentials.Similar stack overflow posts [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68491311/exception-503-failed-to-connect-to-all-addresses-when-pulishing-data-to-google) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58168189/serviceunavailable-503-failed-to-connect-to-all-addresses-during-attempt-to-rec)